# My solution of leetcode 753 has a mysterious bug : using HashSet instead of Set as reference to object will cause StackOverFlow, Why?

Tags: java

Using HashSet instead of Set as reference will cause **StackOverFlow**, does anyone know why?
I used this solution : https://leetcode.com/problems/cracking-the-safe/discuss/110264/Easy-DFS 
The funny thing is that a slight change of it will cuase **StackOverFlow**.
I wrote two version, the **only difference** of them is the first one pass **HashSet** and the second one pass **Set** to the dfs() function as parameter.
 **This one will stackoverflow**

```
public String crackSafe(int n, int k) {

    int total = (int)Math.pow(k, n);
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sb.append('0');
    set.add(sb.toString());
    dfs(total, set, sb, k, n);
    return sb.toString();
}

private boolean dfs(int total, HashSet<String> set, StringBuilder sb, int k, int n){
    if(set.size() == total)
        return true;
    String prev = sb.toString().substring(sb.length() - n + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        String str = prev + i;
        if(set.contains(str))
            continue;
        set.add(str);
        sb.append(i);
        if(dfs(total, set, sb, k, n))
            return true;
        set.remove(str);
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
    }

    return false;
}
```

**But this one won't, and it is accepted**

```
public String crackSafe(int n, int k) {

    int total = (int)Math.pow(k, n);
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sb.append('0');
    set.add(sb.toString());
    dfs(total, set, sb, k, n);
    return sb.toString();
}

private boolean dfs(int total, Set<String> set, StringBuilder sb, int k, int n){
    if(set.size() == total)
        return true;
    String prev = sb.toString().substring(sb.length() - n + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        String str = prev + i;
        if(set.contains(str))
            continue;
        set.add(str);
        sb.append(i);
        if(dfs(total, set, sb, k, n))
            return true;
        set.remove(str);
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
    }

    return false;
}
```

```html
While the input is 4 8 I got it:
trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:406)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:93)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:19)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 at Solution.dfs(Solution.java:24)
 
.....
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the stack overflow? That will answer this easily.

Comment: Post the full trace in the answer.

Comment: Again, post it in the question. It's illegible in the comments.

Comment: I already update it to my post, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Interesting one. Try for the inputs - (5,8) (4,9) (3,8)

Comment: Hi, the requirement of this problem is that n will be in the range [1, 4].k will be in the range [1, 10]. while using inputs [3,8], both of them have expected output, while [5,8], both of them will get StackOverflowError. Is it possible that the leetcode limits the size of stack? But why Set and HashSet reference take up different stack size?

Comment: Could be because it resulted in bigger stack frames.

Comment: the requirement of this problem is that n will be in the range [1, 4].k will be in the range [1, 10], k^n will be at most 4096.  Thus while inputing [5,8](illegal), both of them will get StackOverflowError.

Comment: I think you are right